# unmet dependencies,broken packages , trying to install X2GO Server on Zorin Os 16

Tags: linux, debian, installation

I am a new Linux user that's having problems installing X2GO server.

I did have it installed once already and it was working fine and then it got messed up.  I was hoping I could just reinstall the program, however now I'm having problems with broken packages. I'm hoping some smart individual out there can assist me and help me to reinstall
X2GO server.

I'm still very newbie so please have patience with me. I am currently using linux Zorin Os 16.

```
$ sudo apt-get install x2goserver x2goserver-xsession
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 x2goserver : Depends: libfile-which-perl but it is not installable
              Depends: libswitch-perl but it is not installable
              Depends: libx2go-server-perl (< 4.1.0.4-0x2go1.2~git20210925.1939+11.heuler.1.1~) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libx2go-server-perl (>= 4.1.0.4-0x2go1.2~git20210925.1939+11.heuler.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: pwgen but it is not installable
              Depends: x2goserver-x2goagent (< 4.1.0.4-0x2go1.2~git20210925.1939+11.heuler.1.1~) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: x2goserver-x2goagent (>= 4.1.0.4-0x2go1.2~git20210925.1939+11.heuler.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: x2goserver-x2gokdrive (< 4.1.0.4-0x2go1.2~git20210925.1939+11.heuler.1.1~) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: x2goserver-x2gokdrive (>= 4.1.0.4-0x2go1.2~git20210925.1939+11.heuler.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: x11-xfs-utils but it is not installable
              Recommends: x2goserver-extensions (< 4.1.0.4-0x2go1.2~git20210925.1939+11.heuler.1.1~) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: x2goserver-extensions (>= 4.1.0.4-0x2go1.2~git20210925.1939+11.heuler.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: x2goserver-fmbindings (< 4.1.0.4-0x2go1.2~git20210925.1939+11.heuler.1.1~) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: x2goserver-fmbindings (>= 4.1.0.4-0x2go1.2~git20210925.1939+11.heuler.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: x2goserver-printing (< 4.1.0.4-0x2go1.2~git20210925.1939+11.heuler.1.1~) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: x2goserver-printing (>= 4.1.0.4-0x2go1.2~git20210925.1939+11.heuler.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Sources.list

Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/zorinos/stable/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-zorinos-stable,a=focal,n=focal,l=Zorin OS Stable,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/zorinos/stable/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-zorinos-stable,a=focal,n=focal,l=Zorin OS Stable,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 999 http://ppa.launchpad.net/zorinos/patches/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-zorinos-patches,a=focal,n=focal,l=Zorin OS Patches,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 999 http://ppa.launchpad.net/zorinos/patches/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-zorinos-patches,a=focal,n=focal,l=Zorin OS Patches,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/zorinos/drivers/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-zorinos-drivers,a=focal,n=focal,l=Zorin OS Drivers,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/zorinos/drivers/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-zorinos-drivers,a=focal,n=focal,l=Zorin OS Drivers,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/zorinos/apps/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-zorinos-apps,a=focal,n=focal,l=Zorin OS Apps,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/zorinos/apps/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-zorinos-apps,a=focal,n=focal,l=Zorin OS Apps,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 999 https://packages.zorinos.com/patches focal/main i386 Packages
     release o=Zorin OS,a=focal,n=focal,l=Zorin OS Patches,c=main,b=i386
     origin packages.zorinos.com
 999 https://packages.zorinos.com/patches focal/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Zorin OS,a=focal,n=focal,l=Zorin OS Patches,c=main,b=amd64
     origin packages.zorinos.com
 500 http://packages.x2go.org/debian buster/main i386 Packages
     release o=X2Go,a=stable,n=buster,l=X2Go,c=main,b=i386
     origin packages.x2go.org
 500 http://packages.x2go.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
     release o=X2Go,a=stable,n=buster,l=X2Go,c=main,b=amd64
     origin packages.x2go.org
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/x2go/stable/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-x2go-stable,a=focal,n=focal,l=X2Go stable (main) PPA,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/x2go/stable/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-x2go-stable,a=focal,n=focal,l=X2Go stable (main) PPA,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main i386 Packages
     release o=TeamViewer GmbH,a=stable,l=TeamViewer,c=main,b=i386
     origin linux.teamviewer.com
 500 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     release o=TeamViewer GmbH,a=stable,l=TeamViewer,c=main,b=amd64
     origin linux.teamviewer.com
 500 https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Artifactory,a=public,n=public,l=Artifactory,c=main,b=amd64
     origin downloads.plex.tv
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-gezakovacs,a=focal,n=focal,l=UNetbootin PPA,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-gezakovacs,a=focal,n=focal,l=UNetbootin PPA,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://packages.x2go.org/debian bullseye/heuler armhf Packages
     release o=X2Go,a=testing,n=bullseye,l=X2Go,c=heuler,b=armhf
     origin packages.x2go.org
 500 http://packages.x2go.org/debian bullseye/heuler i386 Packages
     release o=X2Go,a=testing,n=bullseye,l=X2Go,c=heuler,b=i386
     origin packages.x2go.org
 500 http://packages.x2go.org/debian bullseye/heuler amd64 Packages
     release o=X2Go,a=testing,n=bullseye,l=X2Go,c=heuler,b=amd64
     origin packages.x2go.org
 500 http://packages.x2go.org/debian bullseye/main armhf Packages
     release o=X2Go,a=testing,n=bullseye,l=X2Go,c=main,b=armhf
     origin packages.x2go.org
 500 http://packages.x2go.org/debian bullseye/main i386 Packages
     release o=X2Go,a=testing,n=bullseye,l=X2Go,c=main,b=i386
     origin packages.x2go.org
 500 http://packages.x2go.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
     release o=X2Go,a=testing,n=bullseye,l=X2Go,c=main,b=amd64
     origin packages.x2go.org
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin archive.ubuntu.com
Pinned packages:
```

Comment: add the contents of sources.list to ypor question

Comment: Ok thank-you Madhubala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zorin OS 16 is based on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. You have added Debian repositories Buster and Bullseyes which break your configuration.

First, remove `buster` and `bullseyes` from your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the files under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. Once done run `sudo apt update`.

X2Go is available for Ubutnu version >= 18.04 from the official repositories. (older Ubuntu version may use `ppa:x2go/stable` PPA)

The X2Go server can be installed through:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install x2goserver
```

The client:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install x2goclient
```

Comment: Thank-you GAD3R :-)   That did fix my problem. You where a great help. Merry Christmas to you and your family.

Comment: @qmark Great don't forget to accept my answer, please. Thank you too.